# How to set yAxis value in highcharts

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am using highcharts.js
How to set `y` axis value like this.

```
yAxis : 0, 10k,100k,1m,10m,100m
```

Can you edit this link:

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sankars/bvhqLe4s/)

Comment: You can't have 0 on a logarithmic scale, and the rest of your values don't quite mesh with a logarithmic scale either.  If you set the max to 100,000,000, or provide data that goes that high, the chart will draw appropriate axis labels similar to what you want - http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/bvhqLe4s/1/

Comment: it is possible or not?

Comment: @jlbriggs explains you how it works, so let us know what is incorrect with that?

Comment: If you want specifically those axis values, and a logarithmic scale, no it is not possible. If you are flexible on the exact values, and want a logarithmic scale, yes it is possible. If you want those exact values, but don't need a logarithmic scale, yes it is possible.  You can always fake it with a second y axis - one axis to plot the values on, another axis to list the faked labels...